# Sqlite crashes on open

Tags: sqlite, uwp

I try to run some basic code to test Sqlite in y project and the project always stops/exits on the call to Open().

Then in the debug window, I see that *"Activation of the Windows Store app 'f398a499-0092-462e-9b50-aab3651b4b69_kxamnsbhqvv2e!App' failed with error 'Windows was unable to communicate with the target application.  This usually indicates that the target application's process aborted. More information may be available in the Debug pane of the Output window (Debug->Windows->Output)'."*

Version of Microsoft.Data.Sqlite is 1.0.0
Version of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform is 6.0.6

Here is my code :

```
                SqliteEngine.UseWinSqlite3(); //Configuring library to use SDK version of SQLite
                using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=sqliteSample.db"))
                {
                    db.Open();
                    var tableCommand = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (Primary_Key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Text_Entry NVARCHAR(2048) NULL)";
                    var createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand, db);
                    try
                    {
                        createTable.ExecuteReader();
                    }
                    catch (SqliteException e)
                    {
                        //Do nothing
                    }
                }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the version of Sqlite to 1.1.1 and now it works.